# How to activate jQuery function with img instead of button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently coding a website using HTML, CSS and JS. I have used a code found on here to make two images on top of each other fade out to expose the other image on the click of a button (creating the effect of a changing img).

However, I don't want there to be an ugly `<input type="button">` on the page to activate the fade, instead, I would like to be able to click an image for the toggle function to be called. How would I go about changing the element that activates the function?

JS code:

```
$(function(){
   $("input:button").click(function(){
      $(".logo").fadeToggle("fast");
   });
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Go Kitty Go"/>
```

CSS:

```
#logo1 {
  position:absolute;
  top:9px;
  left: 46%;
  height: 29px;
  width: 89px;
}

#logo2 {
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top: 8.5px;
  left: 48.2%;
  height: 28px;
  width: 60px;
}

input {
  position:absolute;
  top: 220px;
}
```

I would like to swap the `button` with an `img` to activate the `fadeToggle()` function.

Comment: if you want jquery run on img then use image id instead of input:button.

Comment: click event works on img element too not just button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You havn't posted your full html so I don't know what your `img` tags look like. But assuming you have given them an id (`id="someId"`), do this:

```
$("#someId").click(function(){
    $(".logo").fadeToggle("fast");
}); `});`
```

The only change here is that instead of listening for the click on your button, your code is now listening for the click on your img

Comment: Perfect, thats what I was looking for, Thanks millerbr.

Comment: No problem. Remember to click the tick so future users know this answer works! :D

Comment: Remember this functionality won't work for users who don't have or are physically unable to use a mouse or other pointing device.